# Поиск класса в HTML имя которого содержит определённую фразу

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Столкнулся с проблемой при работе с сайтом через selenium на python. Проблема состоит в том, что мне нужно найти определённый элемент по его классу, но иногда название класса частично меняется:

Было `some-name-123` стало `some-name-431`, цифры создаются случайно, т.е. рассмотреть два варианта, как я думал сначала нельзя.

Код которым я получаю объект:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(config.WEBSITE)

    ...
    ...
    ...

button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("some-name-123")

    ...
    ...
    ...
```

Как мне сделать так, что бы скрипт находил все элементы имя класса которых содержит `some-name-` не зависимо от трёх последних цифр?

P.s. Такой элемент на странице всегда один

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался! Вот решение:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class,'some-name')]")
```